The set of limit points of a continuous function at infinity form a closed subset.
Let $f :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}  $ be a continuous function and $S=\{ l \in \mathbb{R} \mid \exists$ a sequence $\{a_n \} $ s.t $ a_n \rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty $ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(a_n)=l \}$
Prove $S$ is closed.
My attempt:
Case(I)
If $\lim_{ x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)= l $  exist finitely . Then $S=\{l\}$  is closed.
Case (II)
If $f(x)$ is unbounded as $x\rightarrow \infty$ ,then $S=\emptyset$.
Case(III)
$\lim_{ x\rightarrow \infty} f(x)$ doesn't exist either finitely or infinitely .
Let $x \in S'$ (the derived set ) .Then there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $S$ converging to $x$.
We want to show $x\in S$ or $\exists$ a sequence $\{a_n \} $ s.t $ a_n \rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty $ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(a_n)=x$
Since each $x_m $ is a point of $S$ there is a sequence $\{x_{m,n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that  $x_{m,n} \rightarrow \infty$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(x_{m,n}) = x_m$
I want to consider the sequence $\{x_{n,n}\}$ and use continuity of $f$ but I am pretty much clueless how to proceed from here .
This results sound similar to the fact that set of all subsequential limits of a sequence in a metric space is closed but since the question involves functional values I find it different.
Hints Please.

Is it acceptable to use the definition of a closed set as a complement of an open set? Specifically a set $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is closed if for any $y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus X$ there is $r > 0$ such that $(y-r, y+r)$ is disjoint from $X$.

There is no specific instructions. Would love to hear your idea :)

Let $(\ell_n)\in S^{\mathbb N}$ a sequence that converges to $\ell$. If $n \in\mathbb N$ fixed, let $(a_{n,m})_{m\in\mathbb N}$ with $a_{n,m}\to \infty $ if $m\to \infty $ s.t. $$\lim_{m\to \infty }f(a_{n,m})=\ell_n.$$
In particular, for all $n$, there is $N_n>n$ s.t. $a_{n,N_n}>n$ and $$\ell_n-\frac{1}{n}\leq f(a_{n,N_n})\leq \ell_n+\frac{1}{n}.$$
Set $b_n=a_{n,N_n}\to \infty $ if $n\to \infty$ . Then, $$\lim_{n\to \infty }f(b_n)=\ell,$$
and thus, $\ell\in S$ as wished.

The idea is correct, but you didn't account for the "$a_n \to \infty$" part.

@Adayah: fixed ;-)

@Surb Can you please prove why $b_n \rightarrow \infty$

@user-492177: $b_n>n$ for all $n$.

@Surb thanks now it's clear :)

Let us first prove
$$S = \left\{ y \in \mathbb{R} : (\forall x_0 \in \mathbb{R})(\forall r > 0) \, f \big( [x_0, \infty) \big) \cap (y-r, y+r) \neq \varnothing \right\}. \tag{$\ast$}$$
Indeed, if $y \in S$, then there is $a_n \to \infty$ such that $f(a_n) \to y$. Given $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $r > 0$, all sufficiently large $n \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfy $a_n \geqslant x_0$ and $f(a_n) \in (y-r, y+r)$, hence $y$ belongs to the RHS.
On the other hand, suppose $y$ belongs to the RHS. Then for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we have that
$$f \big( [n, \infty) \big) \cap \left( y - \frac{1}{n}, y + \frac{1}{n} \right) \neq \varnothing.$$
It follows that we can find $a_n \in [n, \infty)$ such that $f(a_n) \in \left( y - \frac{1}{n}, y + \frac{1}{n} \right)$. Then the sequence $(a_n)$ satisfies $a_n \to \infty$ and $f(a_n) \to y$, thus $y \in S$. $\square$
Taking complements, we get
$$\mathbb{R} \setminus S = \left\{ y \in \mathbb{R} : (\exists x_0 \in \mathbb{R})(\exists r > 0) \, f \big( [x_0, \infty) \big) \cap (y-r, y+r) = \varnothing \right\}.$$
Now we prove that $S$ is closed using the definition: $S$ is closed if for any $y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus S$ there is $r > 0$ such that $(y-r, y+r)$ is disjoint from $S$. So take any $y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus S$. By the above, we can find $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $r > 0$ such that $f \big( [x_0, \infty) \big) \cap (y-r, y+r) = \varnothing$. It remains to check that $(y-r, y+r)$ is disjoint from $S$.
Take any $z \in (y-r, y+r)$ and pick $s > 0$ so that $(z-s, z+s) \subseteq (y-r, y+r)$. Then $f \big( [x_0, \infty) \big) \cap (z-s, z+s) = \varnothing$, so the pair $(x_0, s)$ is a witness that $z \in \mathbb{R} \setminus S$.

This is way longer than I thought, the other answer is just better. At least I hope there is some instructive value here.
